# Dynamic centered header bar with CSS

Tags: html, css

currently I have this header bar

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  background: gray;
}

.box {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

and I want the containers align themselves in the center of the parent.

[image]

As you can see I always want the bar being centered when adding more divs or remove some of them.

Comment: Why don't you just use `justify-content: center` on the parent and play with children margins to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `justify-content: space-around` rule:

```css
#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  background: gray;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hm yes this is really nice but is there a way to remove the big space between them?

Comment: AFAIK you'd have to use margins on the inner divs to tweak the spacing further.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `justify-content: space-evenly;`. The difference between `space-around` and `space-evenly` is that space around has less space towards the (left and right) edges of the parent container, whereas the space in `space-evenly` is similar everywhere.

```css
#header {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  background: gray;
}

.box {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background: red;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

[Here is a good](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) resource for flexbox.

Comment: I was thinking of using space-evenly except it has poor browser compatibility for some reason